# XSD: map and rename list of same elements within the main list to different fields

Tags: excel, xml, xsd

I have an exported xml similar to the following:

```xml
<divesites>
<site uuid='fb5d20c9' name='Name X' gps='40.123456 10.123456' description='type 1'>
  <geo cat='2' origin='0' value='Netherlands'/>
  <geo cat='3' origin='0' value='Zeeland'/>
  <geo cat='5' origin='0' value='foo'/>
</site>
<site uuid='febb4a6b' name='Name Y' gps='40.123456 10.123456' description='type 2'>
  <notes>some crazy note this is... </notes>
  <geo cat='2' origin='0' value='Spain'/>
  <geo cat='3' origin='0' value='Mallorca'/>
</site>
</divesites>
```

I try to read this list into excel as a flat list.
The attributes and the "notes" element go alright because they al exist only once.
The problem lies with the list of geo elements.
What I would like to achieve is to map "<geo cat='2' " to an element called Country, "<geo cat='4' " to an element called Town, etc.
So in the end I want to have a list with uuid, name, gps, description, notes and also country, town, etc.

The xsd that I have so far creates multiple rows for 1 site because of the multiple geo elements:

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="divesites" type="divesitesType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="geoType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="cat" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="origin" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="siteType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="notes" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="geoType" name="geo" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="uuid" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="gps" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="description" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="divesitesType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="siteType" name="site" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I think the way to go is with restrictions and patterns but I am not familiar enough with xsd + excel to get this working.
So please help.

Not that excel has some limitations regarding xsd mapping:

```
There are several types of XML schema element constructs Excel doesn't support. The following XML schema element constructs can't be imported into Excel:

<any>    This element allows you to include elements that aren't declared by the schema.

<anyAttribute>    This element allows you to include attributes that aren't declared by the schema.

Recursive structures    A common example of a recursive structure is a hierarchy of employees and managers in which the same XML elements are nested several levels. Excel doesn't support recursive structures more than one level deep.

Abstract elements    These elements are meant to be declared in the schema, but never used as elements. Abstract elements depend on other elements being substituted for the abstract element.

Substitution groups    These groups allow an element to be swapped wherever another element is referenced. An element indicates it's a member of another element's substitution group through the <substitutionGroup> attribute.

Mixed content    This content is declared by using mixed="true" on a complex type definition. Excel doesn't support the simple content of the complex type but does support the child tags and attributes defined in that complex type.
```

Comment: Maybe you can use XSLT to transform your input XML into an XML format easily digestible by Excel

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I could use that in my scenario?
- Preferably I add a schema/stylesheet to a xlsm workbook only once.
- importing new version of the xml should be only a few clicks and easy. 

So can the style sheet be integrated into excel and/or into the schema?

Comment: XSLT step is independent from Excel: step #1 XSLT transformation,  step#2 Excel.